# Interface declaring a function with function parameter

Tags: typescript

An interface declares a function that accepts a function as a parameter. Why the compiler does not throw an error if an implementation doesn't have such parameter? Is there a possibility to force this behaviour?

```js
interface Iterable2<T> {
    iterate(callback: (element: T) => void): void;
}

class NumberIterable2 implements Iterable2<number> {
    iterate(): void {
        // no error?
    }
}
```

Tested with:

```
deno 1.19.0 (release, x86_64-pc-windows-msvc)
v8 9.9.115.7
typescript 4.5.2
```

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters